# How to separate elements from textfile based on substring of element into 2 output files

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, txt

I have a long lists of animal identifiers in a text file. Our convention is to use two of alphabetical characters, followed by a litter identifier a dash and then the animal id within that litter. The number before the dash identifies whether they are control or manipulated animals.

So it looks like this: (with explanations in parentheses not in the text file) The only things in the text file are the identifier and possibly a data after that identifier on the same line.

XL20-4 is a control animal (0 - even),

XL21-4 is a manipulated animal (1 - odd),

Running all the way to the 300s

```
XL304-5 (4 - even - control), 
XL303-4 (3 - odd - manipulated).
```

First how to create an ordered list in separate textfiles of the animals in each condition from the original text file, so it can then be read by our matlab code.

It needs to retain the order of animal generation within those new textfiles
i.e.

```
XL302-4, 
XL304-5, 
XL304-6, 
XL306-1,
```

Each with a '/n' ending.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you have a text file that you want to sort the identifiers `XL20-4` first by the first number `20` and then by the second number `4`? How have you read in the identifers to get close to this?

Comment: Hi Andrew thanks for your comment. My instinct here is to import regex, read the filelist in as normal, create two new filelists (one for manipulated, one for control), iterate through the original text line by line with a re.split at 'L' and '-' to isolate the litter ID. Convert to an int, another for loop for the working set of identifiers, IF/else using modulus 2 to determine whether it's odd or even. if even, rejoin the line and write it to control textfile, if odd rejoin the line and write it to manipulated textfile. 

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

based on what you had said this would be the way to do it, but there should be some finer tweaking because the file contents originally are unknown (name and how they are placed in the text file)

```
import re

def write_to_file(file_name, data_to_write):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        for item in data_to_write:
            file.write(f"{item}\n")

# read contents from file
with open('original.txt', 'r') as file:
    contents = file.readlines()

# assuming that each of the 'XL20-4,' are on a new line
control_group = []
manipulated_group = []
for item in contents:
    # get only the first number between the letters and dash
    test_generation = int(item[re.search(r"\d", item).start():item.find('-')])
    if test_generation % 2: # if even evaluates to 0 ~ being false
        manipulated_group.append(item)
    else:
        control_group.append(item)

# write to files with the data
write_to_file('control.txt', control_group)
write_to_file('manipulated.txt', manipulated_group)
```

Comment: Andrew, thank you so much. I have fine tuned the extra stuff. There's just one minor problem. Some filelists I am using have the following:

XL20-2 (20-4-17) - where the bracketed content is the date. This throws up an error to be expected.

`File "C:\Users\etc\txt.py", line 19, in main
    test_generation = int(item[re.search(r"\d", item).start():item.rfind('-')])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11-3 (07-11'`

I replaced the filelist with one I mocked up using just the 
XL-20-3 and it works fine. So the problem seems to be with the date on the  end. Any ideas?

Comment: @ClichéGuevara instead of using item.rfind() just use item.find()